# How do you use a private registry with Docker?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-toolbox

I followed the tutorial

https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#deploy-the-app-on-the-swarm-manager

And created my own registry using

https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/blob/master/README.md#quick-start
https://docs.docker.com/registry/#basic-commands
https://blog.docker.com/2013/07/how-to-use-your-own-registry/

However it fails to deploy on the worker nodes with the error `"No such image: 192.168.99.100"`. What is wrong?

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2
docker tag friendlyhello 192.168.99.100:5000/get-started:part2
docker push 192.168.99.100:5000/get-started # Get https://192.168.99.100:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
docker tag friendlyhello localhost:5000/get-started:part2
docker push localhost:5000/get-started:part2
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab
docker service ps getstartedlab_web

ID                  NAME                      IMAGE                                   NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE             ERROR
                      PORTS
o4nbsqccqlm4        getstartedlab_web.1       192.168.99.100:5000/get-started:part2   default             Running             Running 17 minutes ago

qcjtq3gqag9j         \_ getstartedlab_web.1   192.168.99.100:5000/get-started:part2   myvm1               Shutdown            Rejected 17 minutes ago   "No such image: 192.168.99.100â?▌"
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
...
image: 192.168.99.100:5000/get-started:part2
...
```

I tried to use `image: localhost:5000/get-started:part2` in the `docker-compose.yml` file also, but it gave the error `No such image: localhost:5000`.

```
docker stack rm getstartedlab
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab
docker service ps getstartedlab_web

ID                  NAME                      IMAGE                              NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE             ERROR
                 PORTS
k2cck1p7wpg1        getstartedlab_web.1       localhost:5000/get-started:part2   default             Running             Running 10 seconds ago

69km7zabgw6l         \_ getstartedlab_web.1   localhost:5000/get-started:part2   myvm1               Shutdown            Rejected 21 seconds ago   "No such image: localhost:5000â?▌"
```

Windows 8.1, Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302